# C# Path.GetFileName() as well as OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName cuts off the underscores in the filename

Tags: c#, path, filenames, openfiledialog

In my company it is common to name files in the following manner: `210808_Filename.extension`

Unfortunately both of these ways to get the filename failed: `Path.GetFileName()` and `OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName`. In the path itself the underscores exist, but in the filename they get removed.

```
private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string strCheck = "";

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    strConfigPath1 = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    if (strConfigPath1.Length > 6)
    {
        strCheck = strConfigPath1.Substring(strConfigPath1.Length - 6);
    }

    if (strConfigPath1 == "" || strCheck != ".gcode")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected file has to be a GCode file.");
    }
    else
    {
        lblSelectedDocument.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string);
    }
}
```

I know it may not be a well programmed code due to the fact I am bloody new to programming. Sorry for that.

Comment: Not reproductible. The dialog does not remove underscores. Never. `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string);` ? Are you sure ? What do you have in your real code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward way to set the contents of the label, based on the file that the user selects:

```cs
private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        string chosenFilename = openFileDialog.FileName;
        if (Path.GetExtension(chosenFilename).ToLower() == ".gcode")
        {
            lblSelectedDocument.Content = "Valid file. You selected " + chosenFilename;
        }
        else
        {
            lblSelectedDocument.Content = "Invalid file - not a .GCODE file. You selected " + chosenFilename;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblSelectedDocument.Content = "You did not select a file.";
    }
}
```

If the user doesn't select a file, we just set the label to be `You did not select a file.`

If the user did select a file, we check if the file extension is our intended extension. The check is case-insensitive, so `.GCODE`, `.GcOdE`, `.gcode` (etc) will all work. If the user selected a gcode file, the label says the filename is valid and shows the filename.

If the file extension doesn't match, the user must have selected an invalid file. When this occurs we tell them the filename is invalid and show the filename.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to, but theoretically useless) checking for empty string, using DialogResult is better, cleaner and more conventional, and it also avoid weird behavior by using the standard pattern.

Comment: Thank you so much.
My problem itself with the underscore turned out to be an issue with the string display in a lable.

Comment: The test should be `if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)`. The `== true` is required because the dialog returns a nullable bool.

Comment: Also do not check the file extension like that. There are functions in System.IO.Path to get at it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - I've implemented those in the code.